# How to trigger tap event on iOS device whose developer mode is enabled with USB connection

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there any framework that can trigger tap event on iOS device whose developer mode is enabled with USB connection?
I found `libimobiledevice` can get some information form iOS devices, but it cannot send tap command to device.

Comment: for what do you this? You could record tapping with UIUnitTests and test it with your app.

Comment: I want to create an automation tool to control iphone device in a web page.